# EOS VS Ethereum : Is it logical not to charge any transaction fees in public blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions

Ethereum Operating System(EOS) is a platform which is more scalable than ethereum. To execute a transaction in the ethereum network one needs to spend some transaction fees, in EOS one don't need to spend transaction fees.
There are many platforms like EOS who don't charge any transaction fees.

With the help of transaction fees, one can ensure that a smart contract function won't get into infinite loop. If a platform doesn't charge transaction fees a programmer can write an infinite loop in smart contract function. That will not only increase the latency of mining a new block but also anyone in the blockchain network will be able to use computational resources without any restriction.

Is it logical not to charge any transaction fees in public blockchain?

Comment: Very interesting but too broad and very opinionated. Please post this question on Reddit r/Ethereum

Comment: you are saying that EOS is more scalable than Ethereum, do you have proofs of this? By "proofs" I mean benchmarks, because nowadays everyone got a scalable blockchain, but nobody has any proof of that. Also, this proof must specify the length of contract's bytecode that was used in tests, because the length of code and the amount of instructions it contains will affect the measurements.

Answer (score 1):

The transaction fee is one of the most proven mechanism needed to have a truly decentralized network: people can decide to issue a node in order to cash the fees and if this mechanism can last forever, the blockchain shall last forever as well.

On the contrary if someone pays miner for your transaction by means of some mechanism different from fees, that “someone” is empowered in managing the life your application too. For instance he can switch off the network refusing to further pay miners and you are out.

It is not so reccomandable, even if some other mechanism has been implemented to ensure the sustainability of the network: transaction fee for miners works, the new mechanism is to be proven.

Of course transaction fees is not the only possibility to have and this aspect is not the only one to evaluate, but in my opinion it is one of the most important.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to know more about other mechanisms has been implemented to ensure the sustainability of the network.